# CSS border-image:linear-gradient not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I've got a little CSS square bracket thing going on. It works nicely in Chrome, Firefox, and oddly in IE, but not in Safari!

```
.square-brackets {
padding: 10px 30px;
margin: auto;
border: 5px solid transparent;
border-image:linear-gradient(to right, #92AC3B 0px,#92AC3B 3%, #fff 3%, #fff 98%, #92AC3B 98%, #92AC3B 100%);
border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #92AC3B 0px,#92AC3B 3%, #fff 3%, #fff 98%, #92AC3B 98%, #92AC3B 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing it not to render in Safari?

Comment: You can use SVG, nowadays it is supported in every browser. Than convert it to base64 and use it as background: url('data:...') if you use compass it can convert css gradient to background-image SVG

Comment: Thanks for this, but I've had a good look around and can't get to grips with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this for backwards compatability:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7)));
```

Basically, you need to use both -webkit-gradient and -webkit--linear-gradient.
You can find more information about gradient prefixes here: https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Require-all-gradient-definitions

Comment: Same story I'm afraid: `code`.square-brackets {
padding: 10px 30px;
margin: auto;
border: 5px solid transparent;
border-image:linear-gradient(to right, #92AC3B 0px,#92AC3B 3%, #fff 3%, #fff 98%, #92AC3B 98%, #92AC3B 100%);
border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #92AC3B 0px,#92AC3B 3%, #fff 3%, #fff 98%, #92AC3B 98%, #92AC3B 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
border-image: -webkit-gradient(to right, #92AC3B 0px,#92AC3B 3%, #fff 3%, #fff 98%, #92AC3B 98%, #92AC3B 100%);
border-image-slice: 1;
}`code`

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it works in the latest Safari browsers. The latest Safari I can load onto my PC is ancient. I didn't realise Apple didn't offer newer versions for Windows any more!!